# Is there anyway to convert long to int?

Tags: c#, casting, integer, long-integer

Maybe this is a stupid question: I have accidentally cast long value to int value in the database (~ 1M rows), so is there any way to revert it back using code (without restoring the database)? Thanks

Example:
My long value: **636705792000000000**

Int value after cast: **1587019776**

==> Is there any way to find 636705792000000000 when I have only int value (1587019776)

Comment: No, there is no way to do that, you have lost your data I'm afraid.

Comment: No. You lost half of value. If you convert values to hex, you can clearly see how the value was stripped off and what you loose. long value = 0x08D6088B 5E980000, int value = 0x5E980000

Comment: You've got to restore because your `long` values are beyond the limits of `int`

Comment: DavidG, Reniuz and Fabulous: Thank for your helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you have effectively blanked out half of your data I'm afraid. If you convert those numbers to binary, it may be more obvious:

```
636705792000000000 => ‭100011010110000010001000101101011110100110000000000000000000‬
        1587019776 =>                             ‭01011110100110000000000000000000‬
```

Note how the right hand half of the `long` is the same as the entirety of the `int`. However, you have completely lost the left half.